# How can I correct this switch case in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, switch-statement

So I've been working on this code for a while and it has me a bit lost. Keep in mind I am extremely new to Java and so I'm a bit slow on the uptake. I have created shape classes that implement an interface with getArea, getPerimeter and getDescription methods. There are multiple shapes but that isn't really where the problem is. The problem comes when I attempt to implement switch cases to allow the user to choose which shape he or she wants to add. I am getting the same message as many times as the Array of shapes will allow the address of the Shape I try to add. I realize the mistake I'm making is most likely a beginner one by I would really appreciate some help, Thank you. Also if you could give me a clue on how to sort the Shapes by their Area it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class ShapeApp2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Shape[] test = new Shape[10];
     System.out.println("Choose a shape or type stop to break away?");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     String Shape = sc.nextLine();

     for (int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {

     switch (Shape) {
         case "Rectangle":
             System.out.println("You have chosen a Rectangle");
             test[i] = new Rectangle();
             System.out.println("Enter another one now");
             break;
         case "Square":
             System.out.println("You have chosen a Square");
             test[i] = new Square();
             System.out.println("Enter another one now");
             break;         
         case "Equilateral Triangle":
             System.out.println("You have chosen an Equilateral Triangle");
             test[i] = new Equilateral_Triangle();
             System.out.println("Enter another one now");
             break;
         case "Right Triangle":
             System.out.println("You have chosen a Right Triangle");
             test[i] = new Right_Triangle();
             System.out.println("Enter another one now");
             break;
         case "Isosceles Triangle":
             System.out.println("You have chosen an Isosceles Triangle");
             test[i] = new Isosceles_Triangle();
             System.out.println("Enter another one now");
             break;
         case "Scalene Triangle":
             System.out.println("You have chosen a Scalene Triangle");
             test[i] = new Scalene_Triangle();
             System.out.println("Enter another one now");
             break;
         case "Stop":
             break;
      }
         System.out.println(test[i]);
     }

}
```

}

Also here's a couple of the Shape Classes for context.

```
package shapeapp2;

/**
 *
 * @author my-pc
 */
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private String shapeName;
    public Rectangle(){
        length = 4.0;
        width = 5.0;
        shapeName = "Rectangle";
    }
     public double getArea(){
         double Area;
         Area = length * width;
         return Area;
     }
     public double getPerimeter() {
         double Perimeter;
         Perimeter = (2*length) + (2*width);
         return Perimeter;
     }
     public String getDescription() {
         return shapeName;
     }
}



 package shapeapp2;

/**
 *
 * @author my-pc
 */
public class Square implements Shape {
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private String shapeName;
    public Square(){
        length = 8.0;
        width = 8.0;
        shapeName = "Square";
    }
     public double getArea(){
         double Area;
         Area = length * width;
         return Area;
     }
     public double getPerimeter() {
         double Perimeter;
         Perimeter = (2*length) + (2*width);
         return Perimeter;
     }
     public String getDescription() {
         return shapeName;
     }
}
```

Comment: You currently ask for user input a single time before you enter the loop, so it never changes afterwards. You have to move `sc.nextLine()` *inside* the loop, so the user is asked again each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading the shape from the user once before the loop. You wanted to read it in the loop. That's the only thing that would make sense.

```
String Shape = sc.nextLine();
for (int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    String Shape = sc.nextLine();
```

Also, you should rename that variable. `Shape` looks like a classname.